How to build Yocto recipe for Qt Quick app using cmake and Qt 6.7.3
I created a Qt quick app in Qt Creator with CMake using Qt 6.7.3.
Now, I would like to create an embedded Linux image with this app for the stm32mp157f-dk2.
I'm using a VM with Ubuntu 22.04 and set up the Yocto directory with the v6.7.3.xml manifest. Then, I added the meta-st layer.
Then, inside my custom layer, I created a recipe that looks like this:
SUMMARY = "This is the GUI for Hespect Software medical device"
DESCRIPTION = "Recipe created by bitbake-layers"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
SECTION = "Mysection"

DEPENDS += "qtbase"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "qtwayland"

SRC_URI = "file://Backendsensors.h"
SRC_URI = "file://Backendsensors.cpp"
SRC_URI = "file://brushfactory.h"
SRC_URI = "file://brushfactory.cpp"
SRC_URI = "file://main.cpp"
SRC_URI = "file://Main.qml"
SRC_URI = "file://CMakeLists.txt"
            
S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile () {
    cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${STAGING_DIR_NATIVE}/usr/share/cmake/OEToolchain.cmake ${S}
    make
}

do_install () {     
    install -d ${D}/usr/share/mygui/
    install -m 0644 ${S}/assets/images/* ${D}/usr/share/mygui/assets/images/
    install -m 0644 ${S}/Backendsensors.h ${D}/usr/include/
    install -m 0644 ${S}/Backendsensors.cpp ${D}/usr/src/mygui/
    install -m 0644 ${S}/brushfactory.h ${D}/usr/include/
    install -m 0644 ${S}/brushfactory.cpp ${D}/usr/src/mygui/
    install -m 0644 ${S}/main.cpp ${D}/usr/src/mygui/
    install -m 0644 ${S}/Main.qml ${D}/usr/share/mygui/
    install -m 0755 ${B}/main ${D}/usr/bin/
}

These are the files inside the "file" folder:
Backendsensors.cpp 
assets/    
Backendsensors.h
brushfactory.cpp
main.cpp
CMakeLists.txt     
Main.qml            
brushfactory.h

I tried building this recipe with "bitbake mygui" but I got this error:
ERROR: mygui-0-r0 do_compile: ExecutionError('/home/vboxuser/yocto/build-stm32mp15-disco/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/mygui/0/temp/run.do_compile.8991', 127, None, None)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/vboxuser/yocto/build-stm32mp15-disco/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/mygui/0/temp/log.do_compile.8991
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| /home/vboxuser/yocto/build-stm32mp15-disco/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/mygui/0/temp/run.do_compile.8991: 141: cmake: not found
| WARNING: exit code 127 from a shell command.
ERROR: Task (/home/vboxuser/yocto/build-stm32mp15-disco/meta-custom/recipes-software/myGUI/mygui_0_1.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3568 tasks of which 3567 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/vboxuser/yocto/build-stm32mp15-disco/meta-custom/recipes-software/myGUI/mygui_0_1.bb:do_compile
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message, returning a non-zero exit code

When I call cmake --version I get 3.22, so it's there.
I already tried different versions of the recipe but no luck so far.

It seems part of the problem was that I missed "inherit qt6-cmake". I added it and the build continue with another error "qtcharts" not found. I added it in the dependencies and that fixed that error.
Now, there's another error that says it can't find main.cpp file, even tough is right there in the file folder.
CMake Error at recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/cmake/Qt6Core/Qt6CoreMacros.cmake:634 (add_executable):
|   Cannot find source file:
| 
|     main.cpp
| 
|   Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .mpp .m .M .mm .ixx .cppm
|   .ccm .cxxm .c++m .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx .f .F .for .f77 .f90
|   .f95 .f03 .hip .ispc
| Call Stack (most recent call first):
|   recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/cmake/Qt6Core/Qt6CoreMacros.cmake:575 (_qt_internal_create_executable)
|   recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/cmake/Qt6Core/Qt6CoreMacros.cmake:875 (qt6_add_executable)
|   CMakeLists.txt:11 (qt_add_executable)
| 
| 
| -- Generating done (0.0s)
| CMake Warning:
|   Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
| 
|     CMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY
|     FETCHCONTENT_FULLY_DISCONNECTED
|     INSTALL_ARCHDATADIR
|     INSTALL_BINDIR
|     INSTALL_DATADIR
|     INSTALL_DESCRIPTIONSDIR
|     INSTALL_DOCDIR
|     INSTALL_EXAMPLESDIR
|     INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR
|     INSTALL_LIBDIR
|     INSTALL_LIBEXECDIR
|     INSTALL_MKSPECSDIR
|     INSTALL_PLUGINSDIR
|     INSTALL_QMLDIR
|     INSTALL_SYSCONFDIR
|     INSTALL_TESTSDIR
|     INSTALL_TRANSLATIONSDIR
|     LIB_SUFFIX
|     PYTHON_EXECUTABLE
|     Python3_EXECUTABLE
|     Python_EXECUTABLE
|     QT_BUILD_INTERNALS_NO_FORCE_SET_INSTALL_PREFIX
|     QT_CMAKE_DEBUG_EXTEND_TARGET
|     QT_FORCE_BUILD_TOOLS
|     __harfbuzz_broken_config_file
| 
| 
| CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Task (/home/vboxuser/yocto/build-stm32mp15-disco/meta-custom/recipes-software/myGUI/mygui_0_1.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3853 tasks of which 3829 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
NOTE: Build completion summary:
NOTE:   do_populate_sysroot: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_deploy_source_date_epoch: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 2 scratch)
NOTE:   do_create_spdx: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_create_runtime_spdx: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_package_qa: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_recipe_qa: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_package: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_packagedata: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_package_write_ipk: 99.0% sstate reuse(95 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_populate_lic: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/vboxuser/yocto/build-stm32mp15-disco/meta-custom/recipes-software/myGUI/mygui_0_1.bb:do_configure
Summary: There was 1 WARNING message.
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message, returning a non-zero exit code.

CMake Error at recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/cmake/Qt6Core/Qt6CoreMacros.cmake:634 (add_executable):
|   Cannot find source file:
| 
|     main.cpp
| 
|   Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .mpp .m .M .mm .ixx .cppm
|   .ccm .cxxm .c++m .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx .f .F .for .f77 .f90
|   .f95 .f03 .hip .ispc
| Call Stack (most recent call first):
|   recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/cmake/Qt6Core/Qt6CoreMacros.cmake:575 (_qt_internal_create_executable)
|   recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/cmake/Qt6Core/Qt6CoreMacros.cmake:875 (qt6_add_executable)
|   CMakeLists.txt:11 (qt_add_executable)
| 
| 
| -- Generating done (0.0s)
| CMake Warning:
|   Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
| 
|     CMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY
|     FETCHCONTENT_FULLY_DISCONNECTED
|     INSTALL_ARCHDATADIR
|     INSTALL_BINDIR
|     INSTALL_DATADIR
|     INSTALL_DESCRIPTIONSDIR
|     INSTALL_DOCDIR
|     INSTALL_EXAMPLESDIR
|     INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR
|     INSTALL_LIBDIR
|     INSTALL_LIBEXECDIR
|     INSTALL_MKSPECSDIR
|     INSTALL_PLUGINSDIR
|     INSTALL_QMLDIR
|     INSTALL_SYSCONFDIR
|     INSTALL_TESTSDIR
|     INSTALL_TRANSLATIONSDIR
|     LIB_SUFFIX
|     PYTHON_EXECUTABLE
|     Python3_EXECUTABLE
|     Python_EXECUTABLE
|     QT_BUILD_INTERNALS_NO_FORCE_SET_INSTALL_PREFIX
|     QT_CMAKE_DEBUG_EXTEND_TARGET
|     QT_FORCE_BUILD_TOOLS
|     __harfbuzz_broken_config_file
| 
| 
| CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Task (/home/vboxuser/yocto/build-stm32mp15-disco/meta-custom/recipes-software/myGUI/mygui_0_1.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3853 tasks of which 3829 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
NOTE: Build completion summary:
NOTE:   do_populate_sysroot: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_deploy_source_date_epoch: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 2 scratch)
NOTE:   do_create_spdx: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_create_runtime_spdx: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_package_qa: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_recipe_qa: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_package: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_packagedata: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_package_write_ipk: 99.0% sstate reuse(95 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_populate_lic: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/vboxuser/yocto/build-stm32mp15-disco/meta-custom/recipes-software/myGUI/mygui_0_1.bb:do_configure
Summary: There was 1 WARNING message.
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message, returning a non-zero exit code.

The CMakelist.txt file is the one directly created by Qt Creator, and I just ran the application in qt creator, and it worked fine, so I suppose it finds the main.cpp.

The problem was that I needed to use SRC_URI +=, instead or SRC_URI =.
Then, I read on another post that qt6-cmake added the assets without needing to explicitly tell it to do it, but I had to add them with SRC_URI =+ because they weren't being found.
Then, I had a typo and that was it, the recipe baked successfully.
